# How to deploy telephony code changes in Android 5.0?

Tags: apk, android-5.0-lollipop, android-source, android-install-apk

It seems like I am unable to deploy changes made to `packages/service/Telecom/*.java` unless I flash the entire image file, which is time consuming.

I am working off the Android aosp 5.0 branch and I made a small change to the `com.android.server.telecom.CallActivity class` (e.g. `Log.i("I am here")` ). I entered "mm" to build to the project under /packages/services/Telecomm and got an updated apk file in `out/target/product/aosp_arm/system/priv-app/Telecom/Telecom.apk` . And then I installed the apk by typing `"adb install -r /path/to/Telecom.apk`". The installer confirmed "success". I rebooted the device and logcat my added log line while making a phone call. However, I saw nothing.

On the other hand, if I do a full build by typing "`make -j8`" from the root of the tree and flash the image zip file using `flashall.sh` or `update.sh`, I can see my added log line.

What did I miss? I am sure there must be a way to make changes in the Telecom package w/o a full rebuilt every time.

Thank you!